# dvdauthor spumux aborted: picture had 256 colors

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd

```
spumux tmp.xml < tmp.mpg > output.mpg
INFO: Picture tmp.png had 255 colors
INFO: Picture tmp.select.png had 256 colors
spumux: subgen.c:313: findmasterpal: Assertion `s->numpal < 16' failed.
.MakeMenus.sh: line 70: 18832 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Picturies created:

```
head -c -1 tmp.txt | convert -background none -size 720x576 -font Courier -pointsize 20 -fill white -gravity center caption:@- tmp.png
head -c -1 tmp.txt | convert -background none -size 720x576 -font Courier -pointsize 20 -undercolor black -fill white -gravity center caption:@- tmp.select.png
```

File tmp.xml:

```
<subpictures format="PAL"><stream>
<spu start="00:00:00.00" force="yes" autoorder="rows" autooutline="infer" outlinewidth="6" image="tmp.png" highlight="tmp.select.png" select="tmp.png">
</spu>
</stream></subpictures>
```

COMMENT:
Spumux, the subtitle multiplexing tool in DVD authoring, supports a limited range of colors for subpictures. Here is a list of some commonly used colors in spumux along with their corresponding hexadecimal color codes:

1. White - #FFFFFF
2. Black - #000000
3. Red - #FF0000
4. Green - #00FF00
5. Blue - #0000FF
6. Yellow - #FFFF00
7. Magenta - #FF00FF
8. Cyan - #00FFFF
9. Gray - #808080
10. Light Gray - #C0C0C0

Remember, spumux has a limit of 16 colors for the subpicture palette, so you should choose your colors from this limited set.

Answer (score 0):

```
head -c -1 tmp.txt | convert -background none -size 720x576 -font Courier -pointsize 20 -undercolor black -fill white -gravity center caption:@- -threshold 50% tmp.select.png
```

The "-threshold 50%" option converts all shades of gray to pure black and white, considering any pixel with a brightness level below 50% as black and anything above as white.